# How do I convert a UNIX timestamp to ISO in CMake

Tags: cmake, unix-timestamp

I have a UNIX-style timestamp that looks like `1587405820 -0600` which I would like to convert to an ISO style format, something like `YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ`

CMake has a `string(TIMESTAMP ...)` command at https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.12/command/string.html#timestamp but this only gets me the *current* time in a formatted string which does not work for my application. I need to be able to convert an existing time into ISO format.

Is there a way to do this?

---

#### UPDATE

Based on @squareskittles answer, here's what I ended up with this test which is doing the right thing:

```
# Check that we get the current timestamp
string(TIMESTAMP TIME_T UTC)
message(STATUS ">>> T1: ${TIME_T}")

# Get the ISO string from our specific timestamp
set(ENV{SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH} 1587405820)
string(TIMESTAMP TIME_T UTC)
unset(ENV{SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH})
message(STATUS ">>> T2: ${TIME_T}")

# Check that we get the current timestamp again correctly
string(TIMESTAMP TIME_T UTC)
message(STATUS ">>> T3: ${TIME_T}")
```

Which gives me this output:

```
-- >>> T1: 2020-04-22T15:08:13Z
-- >>> T2: 2020-04-20T18:03:40Z
-- >>> T3: 2020-04-22T15:08:13Z
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want this function to use a specific time *other than* than the current time, you can [set](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html#set-environment-variable) the environment variable `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` to the UNIX-style timestamp (integer):

```
# Set the environment variable to a specific timestamp.
set(ENV{SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH} 1587405820)
# Convert to ISO format, and print it.
string(TIMESTAMP MY_TIME)
message(STATUS ${MY_TIME})
```

prints (for UTC -0600):

```
2020-04-20T12:03:40
```

If you need to adjust this time to UTC time, you can add the `UTC` argument:

```
set(ENV{SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH} 1587405820)
string(TIMESTAMP MY_TIME UTC)
message(STATUS ${MY_TIME})
```

prints:

```
2020-04-20T18:03:40Z
```

Note: If this `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` variable is used elsewhere in your CMake code, it is best to save the `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` value before modifying it, so it can be set back to its previous value when complete.

Comment: I believe I would advise to reset the `SOURCE_DATE_EPOCH` to previous value after use so not to interfere with rest of the code.

Comment: @KamilCuk That is a good point, so I added a note. The scope of setting an environment variable in CMake like this only affects the current CMake invocation, so the effects would be limited to that.